# How to get left button click only from a tkinter context menu

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to filter out all mouse clicks and wheel events except for `<Button-1>` (the left button) is this possible? In the code below the test function gets executed if the wheel is scrolled or any button is clicked. The code works as it should in Windows but not Linux KDE 5.61.0. I need it to work in Linux too.

```
    from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()

    w = Label(root, text="Right-click to display menu", width=40, height=20)
    w.pack()


    def test(text):
        print(text)


    # create a menu
    popup = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
    popup.add_command(label="Next                ", command=lambda: test('Next Selected'))
    popup.add_command(label="Previous            ", command=lambda: test('Previous Selected'))
    popup.add_separator()
    popup.add_command(label="Home                ", command=lambda: test('Home Selected'))


    def do_popup(event):
        # display the popup menu
        try:
            popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
        finally:
            # make sure to release the grab (Tk 8.0a1 only)
            popup.grab_release()


    w.bind("<Button-3>", do_popup)

    b = Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
    b.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"In the code below the test function gets executed if the wheel is scrolled or any button is clicked."_ - that doesn't happen for me, and I don't see how that's even possible. How are you executing this script? What platform are you on?

Comment: I'm running Linux, and I run it fro the Pycharm IDE.

Comment: I just tested the code in Windows. The code works as it should in Windows but not Linux. I need it to work in Linux too.

Comment: ***"I'm running Linux"**: Which Window Manager?

Comment: Sorry I'm using KDE 5.61.0